# awk line to variable?

Tags: variables, awk

I have the following command which exports out a date in milliseconds. I'm trying to have this stored as a variable so that I can use it later in my script:

```
epochlastUpdated= awk "/<pl:updated>/" feed.rss | head -n 1 | awk -F\< ' { print $2 } ' | awk -F\> ' { print $2 } '| date -j -f "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z" "Fri, 13 Sep 2013 17:16:45 GMT" +%s000
```

I can't seem to get the script to have the output of that line stored in the epochlastUpdated variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store a command execution result, you need

```
var=$(command)
```

In this case,

```
epochlastUpdated=$(awk "/<pl:updated>/" feed.rss | head -n 1 | awk -F\< ' { print $2 } ' | awk -F\> ' { print $2 } '| date -j -f "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z" "Fri, 13 Sep 2013 17:16:45 GMT" +%s000)
```

Answer (score 2):

You got your specific answer but this:

```
awk "/<pl:updated>/" feed.rss | head -n 1 | awk -F\< ' { print $2 } ' | awk -F\> ' { print $2 } '
```

can be done in 1 awk command:

```
awk -F\< '/<pl:updated>/{split($2,a,/>/); print a[2]; exit}' feed.rss
```

It can probably be even simpler than that, it depends what your input actually looks like.

Comment: You miss a `;` here `) print`, should be `);print`

Answer (score 1):

Another short awk version:

```
awk -F"<|>" '/<pl:updated>/ {print $3;exit}' feed.rss
```